# Gatsby - Prismic site breaks when build

Tags: gatsby, react-bootstrap, prismic.io

Not sure I anybody can help me here, but I am building a Gatsby - Prismic site.  It works as expected in Development mode, but when I create the build, something breaks apart.  According to the console while building there is no errors message and seems successful.  I want to share the Netlify url.  In the console (production build), it only shows an error about not loading the images.  The misbehavior occurs as follow.

1. Site does not load properly
2. Images does not load properly Home
   header carousel is not working
3. Navbar links does not load the page
4. If you click a link, url changes, but does not load, if you click
   nav link, have to reload the page for the link to fetch content

Any help or hint or maybe this or that will be appreciated

Netlify testing url 
https://coding-images-prismic.netlify.app/

GitHub repo
https://github.com/codingimages/codingimages-prismic

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're using the useStaticQuery hook. Unfortunately the [gatsby-source-prismic-graphql](https://github.com/birkir/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql) plugin doesn't support useStaticQuery. You'll need to use the StaticQuery component instead as shown [here](https://github.com/birkir/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql#staticquery-and-usestaticquery).

Hopefully that will help make your Gatsby site work in production as well as in development.